# How to remove second whitespace in string, but not first using js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a small text field and if there is more than one whitespace I need to format the string and add a br tag in that second whitespace.  If there isn;t then I do not need to do anything.  I do not need to target the first or third (if there is one) and there will probably not be any after 3 as this is a short title field.  the length of characters will be different and there is not consistent marker, like a comma of period or something, that I can target.

I was unable to find an answer that addressed this.  I did find answers using regex but those all had markers like comma to target, I cannot find on that specifically will only target the second occurrence if there is one so any help would be great appreciated.

Code I have now, which targets only the first occurrence.

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(awardscount, function() {
  var string = $('#award-' + int).attr('data-award-title');

  var refomrattedTitle = string.replace(" ", "<br>");

  int++;
  console.log(refomrattedTitle);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var test = "foo bar string test".replace(/([^\s]*\s[^\s]*)\s/, "$1<br/>");
console.log(test); // logs "foo bar<br/>string test"
```

Comment: perfect, I'll accept the answer as soon as it lets me.